# rails: show nested resource on main resource page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, nested

Not sure if I'm going to describe this correctly:

I've got a 'show' resource and an 'episode' resource; a show can have many episodes. I've got a Show page as well where I list the episodes under that show and (hopefully) have a video player at the top of the show page.  I should also note that I'm using friendly_id.

Theoretically I'd like to do this all in ajax but I'm just getting my head around rails and the pushState /history stuff.

Right now I've got everything 'working' in that a show lists episodes and when clicked I go to the nested Episode page with friendly_id working (ie show/first-show-title/episode/episode-one-title ).

What I'd like ultimately is that every episode has their own url but are displayed in the show page itself -- ie that the params are picked up with the show controller and the correct video loads the episode video in a partial.

Granted I can mock up the episode page to look like the show page and get each episodes 'show' (which is what I'm going to do now until I figure this out) but that's not DRY now is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not bound to use templates of the same name for certain controller actions.
In your EpisodesController simply render the shows page like this

```
def show
    # do stuff, load episode
    render 'shows/show'   # instead of the default 'episodes/show'
end
```

You just need to make sure to satisfy all parameter requirements of your other template. Make use of other `if` conditionals to display certain things if a selected episode is present or not.

---

Another suggestion would require to match that url to the ShowsController#show action and handle the presence of an episode parameter in there.

```
def show
    if params[:episode_title]
        # load episode
    else
        # load other stuff to show overview
    end
end
```

I don't know friendly_id though, so I wouldn't know how to specify that route. Generally the first approach would be more clean since it clearly separates the controllers instead of mashing them together.

Comment: Rocking - that's enough for me to go on; just the fact I can flip it to the other template is fantastic. Thanks!  Totally new to rails but finding it a breath of fresh air after 16 years as a programmer; my biggest 'issue' is not thinking there's a simple approach.

Comment: Actually tried this and instead got the error:    Missing template episodes/shows/show, application/shows/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :arb]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/grimm/Documents/__WORK/RAILS/batterypopv2/app/views"
  * "/Users/grimm/Documents/__WORK/RAILS/batterypopv2/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rich-53dba32858cb/app/views"

Comment: Huh turns out render 'shows/show'  passed it to the controller. Thanks!

Comment: Ah great you found it yourself. I was a bit unsure about it and added the :action param. Seems like it was wrong ;) (fixed it in the reply)